# How can I use a python script to bypass google recaptcha?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, recaptcha

I am trying to create a bot that performs some actions on a website and I tried using rebreak captcha to achieve this but I am not sure how to do this.

I am getting the following error message when running the python script:

```
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, 
but may not work 

warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, 
but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? The repository for this script is on GitHub on this link:

https://github.com/eastee/rebreakcaptcha

Comment: install [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) and/or [avconv](https://libav.org/avconv.html) - there are external programs in C/C++, not in python.

Comment: That's why recaptcha exists. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

If you see the post
https://east-ee.com/2017/02/28/rebreakcaptcha-breaking-googles-recaptcha-v2-using-google/

In the "Update Two" section says:

*"It seems that Google has fully patched this: raising the minimum number of digits from 4-5 to 10-12 and introducing new digit recordings that are harder to speech recognize, as well as background noise. The POC has stopped working as a result. It’s been fun while it lasted"*

Sorry :(